# iOS Spotlight Search - Footnote Text

Tags: ios, corespotlight

I am looking for a way to place a text as footnote in an indexed object. I couldn't find out which field in the `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` it is.

Can anybody, who has experience with this topic, share their experiences?

The footnote in this picture is the URL - I am looking for a way to set this text manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footnote for custom in-app search results is the bundle display name of the app and you **cannot change it** separately from the display name.

Use the `contentDescription` property to provide information about the search result.